# jQuery clear the value from the datepicker field, tied to the checkbox being unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is my scenario: 
I have a form, with a checkbox. 
 - When it is checked, I hide another `<div>` that has a termination date input field, which has a `datepicker`. 
 - When the checkbox is not checked, I want to display the the `<div>` with termination date field. User, clicks on the date, and selects one.

The problem I can't figure out: if after selecting the date, the user checks again the checkbox, how to reset the termination date field to nothing?

I placed the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8gEy/15/).

I already tried what seems like a million ways of doing it, and nothing seems to be working.

Any help with this, is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave it a shot:

http://jsfiddle.net/z8gEy/16/

I simply added after the hide method:

```
$("input[type=date][name$=TerminationDate]").val('');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is insane, though, I tried this gazillion times, but used the tree traversal to look at parents/children to find it, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hdnFromDate = document.getElementById('FromDate').value;
if (hdnFromDate == '') {
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('FromDate'),
        toString(date, format) { // using moment
            return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            // return moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: we use this when the date is cleared but the selection of calendar is not cleared, when using this code on clear function then it working

Comment: Please use [edit] link below your answer to add information to the post and not in comments. Comments can get deleted